# Mejorar la identificacion de las preguntas cerradas

Tags: soporte, preguntas, diseño

Las preguntas cerradas, se identifican con el texto **[cerrada]** al final del titulo de la pregunta, pero muchas veces me ha pasado que cuando voy recorriendo la lista de preguntas no veo esta marca ya que perfectamente puede pasar desapercibida a la vista y las abro, y solo al abrirla es que me doy cuenta que esta pregunta se ha cerrado. Lo que yo propongo es que se haga una identificacion mas obvia quiza un sombreado en rojo, o bien poner el texto **[cerrada]** en algun color llamativo, tal como se hace con las preguntas que tienen las etiquetas que uno sigue las cuales se sombrean de amarillo, o bien las preguntas que ya tienen una respuesta aceptada que se marcan con un color verde a la izquierda de la pregunta.

Comment: No me parece una mala iniciativa, pero lamentablemente estas funcionalidades son a nivel de red por lo que deberían ser propuestas en [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: El sombreado rojo se utiliza para la preguntas eliminadas (que vos todavia no ves). Tal vez, no es que no te diste cuenta de las cerradas, tal vez fue cerrada y como no refrescaste la pantalla, nunca te aparecio el cambio en el titulo... Pero si, no molestaria algo que ayudara a identificarlas mas rapido...

Comment: apoyo la propuesta, la palabra [CERRADA] al Final de los títulos de las post no se percibe; esta debería estar delante del titulo y si es posible ponerles un color naranja al texto [i]que parpadee y que cuando le pases el raton se active un audio que diga este post esta cerrado[/i].